# Error occurs when checking existence of records by linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to check whether records exist under conditions.

This line works fine:

```
DataContext.Alerts.Count(e => e.MemberShip.email == email) > 0
```

This line gives error like "Cannot convert lambda expression to type  because it is not a delegate type"

```
DataContext.Alerts.Contains(e => e.MemberShip.email == email)
```

How can I modify the second statement to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .Alerts.Any(e => e.MemberShip.email == email)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataContext.Alerts.Any(e => e.MemberShip.email == email)`